# Are persons born in U.S. embassies U.S. citizens, if their parents are not citizens?

Tags: united-states, citizenship, fourteenth-amendment

The [Fourteenth Amendment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Text) provides that children born in the United States [become American citizens](http://www.fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/RL33079.pdf) regardless of the citizenship of their parents.

> Section 1. **All persons born or naturalized in the United States, and subject to the jurisdiction thereof, are citizens of the United States and of the State wherein they reside.** No State shall make or enforce any law which shall abridge the privileges or immunities of citizens of the United States; nor shall any State deprive any person of life, liberty, or property, without due process of law; nor deny to any person within its jurisdiction the equal protection of the laws.

There also are rules for who is/isn't a citizen in [territories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_nationality_law#Nationals_who_are_not_citizens) or [former U.S. territories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_nationality_law#Citizenship_at_birth_on_the_U.S._territories_and_former_U.S._territories).

What about U.S. embassies, **Are persons born in U.S. embassies U.S. citizens, even if their parents are not citizens?**

Answer (score 18):

**No, the Fourteenth Amendment does not bestow citizenship by birth in the USA, because an embassy is not part of the USA.**

As the [U.S. Department of State Foreign Affairs Manual Volume 8](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/08FAM/08FAM030101.html) notes, US embassies are not part of the United States and do not acquire U.S. citizenship under the 14th Amendment.

> **8 FAM 301.1-3 NOT INCLUDED IN THE MEANING OF "IN THE UNITED STATES"**
>
> c. Birth on U.S. Military Base Outside of the United States or Birth on U.S. Embassy or Consulate Premises Abroad:
>
> (1) **Despite widespread popular belief, U.S. military installations abroad and U.S. diplomatic or consular facilities abroad are not part of the United States** within the meaning of the 14th Amendment. A child born on the premises of such a facility is not born in the United States and does not acquire U.S. citizenship by reason of birth.

The [US State Department](http://diplomacy.state.gov/discoverdiplomacy/diplomacy101/places/170537.htm) notes:

> U.S. embassies and consulates abroad, as well as foreign embassies and consulates in the United States, have a special status. **While diplomatic spaces remain the territory of the host state**, an embassy or consulate represents a sovereign state. International rules do not allow representatives of the host country to enter an embassy without permission --even to put out a fire -- and designate an attack on an embassy as an attack on the country it represents.

Comment: Nothing wrong with question, but the Q&A format is best suited to each question getting its own post. This allows the correct answers to bubble to the top, where if I answer the Q here, the correct answer might get lost/deleted.That being said,  (No, McCain is eligible to be elected president. 7 FAM 1111a.(2))

Comment: It would be helpful to point out (because some people seem to find it confusing) that being born outside the US does not mean you are not born a US citizen. [Children of US citizens are frequently citizens at birth.](http://montreal.usconsulate.gov/service/qualifying-for-u.s.-citizenship)

Comment: @DJClayworth, I am considering that, but perhaps i should just edit the question to be more clear? "Are persons born in a US embassya US citizen regardless of their parentage?" That is what i was getting at with the 14th amendment background.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign embassies in the USA have some special status, but they *are* on US ground. There is an exception where the newborn baby of a foreign ambassador or his/her wife doesn't become US citizen by birth, but that is due to the status of the parents, not the exact place of birth - I would think that in most cases a baby would be born in a private home or in a hospital anyway, and not in an embassy.

Likewise, if a highly pregnant US citizen enters a foreign embassy, and unexpectedly gives birth, that child will be US citizen by birth.

Comment: Children of most US citizens are US citizens by birth, regardless of where they are born.  The case that's really of interest is that of a non-US citizen, not a diplomat, whose child is born in an embassy to the US.